# How to trigger http requests from Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

In Angular, there is HTTP client https://angular.io/guide/http to communicate with the server in Vue.Js I've not found this functionality. So how to execute HTTP requests in Vue.js?

Comment: You could use axios or fetch API

Answer (score 4):

A good way to make HTTP requests via VueJS is to use [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). They provide easy to use methods and have a good amount of documentation to do so. [Here is an example](https://github.com/axios/axios#example) for how to set up Axios and make a simple HTTP `GET` request. Also, [here is documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) on how responses are formatted by Axios when you make an HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

Add axios lib to your project and try this ;)

```
 <div id="app">
  <div v-if="loading">
    loading...
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="post in posts">
        <h1>
          {{post.title}}
        </h1>
        <p>
          {{post.body}}
        </p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>



const URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
    return {
        loading: true,
      posts: [] // add posts here so reactivity is working, also undefined would be OK
    }
  },
  created() {
    //this.loading = true --> not needed already set in data
    axios.get(URL).then((response) => {
        // console.log(response.data, this)
      this.posts = response.data
      this.loading = false
    })
  }
})
```